# How to change avatar on gmail app for non-gmail account?

Tags: android, email, gmail, avatar

I noticed that in the gmail app, some companies such as Amazon and 1-800-flowers have their company logo next to each message, while others have only the first letter displayed.

How can I achieve the former with a non-gmail account?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do companies set a name and avatar for their automated email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540866/how-do-companies-set-a-name-and-avatar-for-their-automated-email-addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Create a contact with this email account and assign it a picture.